# How to Currency Format used in JSON mode MVC?

Tags: json, model-view-controller

I am new in JSON mode. I am trying to bind such format to model but it does not work. Anyone know this issue?

```
.Column(col =>
{
    col.Add(c => c.Freight).Format("{0:$####.##}").HeaderText("Doller");
    col.Add(c => c.Freight).Format("{0:####.## GBP}").HeaderText("GBP");
    col.Add(c => c.Freight).Format("{0:$####.## JPY}").HeaderText("JPY");
    col.Add(c => c.Freight).Format("{0:####.##}").HeaderText("Rupees");
}
```

Comment: define "not working". any error ?

Comment: Not working If i used date format it is worked

Comment: You should have to specify more details of your question. Means what you have tried and what correct result you got (display your correct result) and what errors you're getting (also display error) so that everybody here can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.Column(col => {
col.Add(c => c.Freight).Format("{$####.##}").HeaderText("Doller");
col.Add(c => c.Freight).Format("{####.## GBP}").HeaderText("GBP");
col.Add(c => c.Freight).Format("{$####.## JPY}").HeaderText("JPY");
col.Add(c => c.Freight).Format("{####.##}").HeaderText("Rupees"); }
```

Comment: I am not suppose to do print $####.##.I need like this format only.